# CSS background size:cover lags browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I use a div with full width and height to show cover background image. And there is a function that slides to left and shows next fullscreen div. The problem is when I use `background-size:cover` the browser lags on slide transition.

I made a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ULah3/1/ and I know I used quality pictures.

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
You can compare this with `background-size:100% auto` http://jsfiddle.net/ULah3/4/

Comment: have you tried preloading images?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: I just tryed it, but its the same: http://jsfiddle.net/ULah3/3/ I don't thinkg the problem is load, but resizing of background.

Comment: This doesn't lag on any of my browsers.